# How to display summed TimeSpans in a custom format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

I need your help with following problem:

I have an ASP.net Grid View and I want to sum times in gridview on cell text and if result is more than 24 Hours then I don't want Days appearing, I need only hours and minutes ( 45:12 ). 
I'm using following code. Please Help.

```
protected void grvCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan sum3 = TimeSpan.Zero;
    if (e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string tt3 = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;

        sum3 += TimeSpan.Parse(tt3);

        llate.Text = string.Format("{0}:{1}", (int)sum3.TotalHours, sum3.Minutes);
    }
}
```

Comment: need result like this format 01:04 not like current 1:4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add together `TimeSpan`s and format the result as total hours and minutes, try something like the following:

```
TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse("21:15");
TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse("14.23:02");
ts1 += ts2;

string hoursMinutes = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", ts1.TotalHours, ts1.Minutes);
```

Comment: @GhalebAlhaddad - You're welcome. There's more on custom string formatting in MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
var j = string.Format("{0:00}",1); //output : 01
var j = string.Format("{0:00}",10); //output : 10
```

Can use this too:

```
var i = 10.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'); //output : 10
var i = 1.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'); //output : 01
```